# Theano strange error on basic RNN

Tags: python, theano, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a beginner in Theano/RNN programming and I made a first simple implementation based on the code [here](https://11350770138305416713.googlegroups.com/attach/2628c6c56beb34bf/rnn.py?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGnDrd7muHLLF-3RV2_0O2ZIl1FqKjvkiMLgr_gdX91v-uw-qJB9axMqCxmqq2uVVmKB9TlyVbHcA8njBSfVW-US24rv6HSdP5EuYoiYI0es6KniIo)

in my code I create as a dataset a simple autoregressive process in which every term of the output series is the sum of the previous 4 values of the input series (normally distributed values)

The full code is

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as TT
#theano.config.exception_verbosity = "high"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SERIES_LEN = 1000;
REGR = 4;
LEARN_RATE = 0.01;
x_train = np.random.randn(SERIES_LEN)
y_train = np.asarray([sum(x_train[range(max(i-REGR,0),i+1)]) for i in range(SERIES_LEN)])
mval = max(y_train)
y_train /= mval
x_train /= mval

x_test = np.random.randn(SERIES_LEN)
y_test = np.asarray([sum(x_test[range(max(i-REGR,0),i+1)]) for i in range(SERIES_LEN)])
mval = max(y_test)
y_test /= mval
x_test /= mval


# number of hidden units
n = 10
# number of input units
nin = 1
# number of output units
nout = 1

# input (where first dimension is time)
u = TT.matrix()
# target (where first dimension is time)
t = TT.matrix()
# initial hidden state of the RNN
h0 = TT.vector()
# learning rate
lr = TT.scalar()
# recurrent weights as a shared variable
W = theano.shared(np.random.uniform(size=(n, n), low=-.01, high=.01))
# input to hidden layer weights
W_in = theano.shared(np.random.uniform(size=(nin, n), low=-.01, high=.01))
# hidden to output layer weights
W_out = theano.shared(np.random.uniform(size=(n, nout), low=-.01, high=.01))


# recurrent function (using tanh activation function) and linear output
# activation function
def step(u_t, h_tm1, W, W_in, W_out):
    h_t = TT.tanh(TT.dot(u_t, W_in) + TT.dot(h_tm1, W))
    y_t = TT.dot(h_t, W_out)
    return h_t, y_t

# the hidden state `h` for the entire sequence, and the output for the
# entrie sequence `y` (first dimension is always time)
[h, y], _ = theano.scan(step,
                        sequences=u,
                        outputs_info=[dict(initial=TT.zeros(n)), None],
                        non_sequences=[W, W_in, W_out],
                        truncate_gradient=REGR)
# error between output and target
error = ((y - t) ** 2).sum()
# gradients on the weights using BPTT
gW, gW_in, gW_out = TT.grad(error, [W, W_in, W_out])
# training function, that computes the error and updates the weights using
# SGD.
fn = theano.function([u, t, lr],
                     error,
                     updates=((W, W - lr * gW),
                              (W_in, W_in - lr * gW_in),
                              (W_out, W_out - lr * gW_out)))


fn(np.atleast_2d(x_train).T, np.atleast_2d(y_train).T, LEARN_RATE)

eval_output = theano.function([u],y)
pred_out = eval_output(x_test)

print pred_out
plt.plot(pred_out)
plt.plot(y_test)
plt.show()
```

there are very few modifications over the basic behavior defined in the linked page. I get a strange error which prevents the program for running further instructions after the line

```
fn(np.atleast_2d(x_train).T, np.atleast_2d(y_train).T, LEARN_RATE)
```

the error that I get is

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_perform_ext.py:133: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
>     from scan_perform.scan_perform import *
>   BLAS error: Parameter incX passed to cblas_dgemv was 0, which is invalid.

I really don't understand how to fix this and have found nothing about this error

Comment: There are actually two parts to the error message. The first part (about a ndarray size changing) is a warning and can be safely ignored. The second part starting "BLAS error:..." is the error to solve. I can't explain the error but it looks like a Theano bug. Can you try updating to the latest bleeding edge version from Github, where it might have already been fixed?

Comment: Do `np.atleast_2d(x_train).T` and `np.atleast_2d(y_train).T` run successfully? If either of these expressions are causing the error then this isn't a Theano bug, it's something happening inside numpy.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Yes actually I had heard of that warning (ndarray size) being harmless and I ignored it, but on a second thought I decided to add it to the description of my problem just in case it was related to the issue. The expressions 'np.atleast_2d(x_train).T' and 'np.atleast_2d(y_train).T' where done by trial and error because the original implementation expected a matrix of examples but I wanted to try it with just one series. Do you think I should create more series and utilize a matrix?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Also, I checked the Theano version and I think it is up to date.

Comment: I can run your code fine -- no errors -- (after a couple of alternations) but I'm probably using a different BLAS library and that seems to be where the error is coming from. I'm also using the latest bleeding edge version of Theano. When you say you updated Theano, do you mean from Github? Updating via pip isn't sufficient.

Comment: Really?? I have version 0.7 and according to the site it should be up to date, isn't it?

Comment: The bleeding edge version of Theano is being updated daily but there is some risk of instability (it may sometimes fail to work at all, or contain more bugs/regressions than the "release" versions). If this is a bug that has been fixed since March then you need the bleeding edge version from Github to resolve the problem. However, another perhaps more likely possibility is that your BLAS contains a bug or is misconfigured/miscompiled. That isn't a Theano problem. Maybe try updating and/or recompiling your BLAS.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look for it. For the moment a workaround is using the instruction `theano.config.blas.ldflags = ""` which tells theano to fallback on calling blas via numpy (not directly). As I've understood it can be slower in some instances but it works for the moment. Thanks again for the help.